# Mass Effect: Andromeda. "Citizen Messages to the Nexus" bug

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

On Aya there's the side mission of collecting messages from citizens with the option of sending them on to the Nexus or editing, then sending. I've sent the messages to the Nexus from the other three, but while the Docks terminal shows me that I have a message, I can't open it for editing/sending. I only have the option to exit as though it were a normal message.  It's the only one that shows up as a mission waypoint

I've updated to the recent patch, I've verified game files, I've left the planet / star system and returned... can't think of anything else to try.

Anyone else have ideas, or is this going to be an incomplete task for me forever?

Comment: It's probably a bug, I remember being able to go up to the hologram terminals around Aya and the datapad popped up and I had the option of sending with or without an edit.

Comment: According to the fandom wiki, there are four terminals. I guess confirm you got all four? http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Task:_Messages_to_the_Nexus

Comment: @DCShannon... Yes, I got all the others. For some reason the Docks Terminal shows me that I have a message, but I can't open it for editing/sending. It's the only one that shows up as a mission waypoint (or whatever it's called) on my map.

Comment: @DCShannon... And the others no longer show the message in the terminal because I have sent them to the Nexus. Only the Docks Terminal shows the message in the terminal, yet I'm not able to send it on to the Nexus.